# Day-count conventions for the floating leg of an asset swap

Tags: swaps, interest-rate-swap, floating-rate, asset

Which is the day-count convention in order to compute the floating leg of an asset swap? I don't know if it is: Act/360, Act/365, 30/360 or 30/365.

Comment: The conventions depend on the currency you are working on. See the following guide for a comprehensive list of day-count conventions for major currencies: https://opengamma.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/Interest-Rate-Instruments-and-Market-Conventions.pdf